# problem with join SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql-server, join, sql-server-2000

I have 3 tables -
Items,
Props,
Items_To_Props

i need to return all items that match all properties that i send
example

```
items
1 
2
3
4

props
T1
T2
T3

items_to_props
1 T1
1 T2
1 T3
2 T1
3 T1
```

when i send T1,T2 i need to get only item 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT T.itemId
  FROM (SELECT itemId, count(distinct prop) propCount
          FROM items_to_props
         WHERE prop in ('T1', 'T2')
      GROUP BY itemId) T
WHERE T.propCount = 2
```

If you don't know how many props you have, you can create a temp table `#P(prop)`, populate it with your props and run the folowing query (will do the same thing):

```
SELECT T.itemId
  FROM (SELECT i.itemId, count(distinct p.prop) propCount
          FROM items_to_props i
          JOIN #P p on i.prop = p.prop
      GROUP BY i.itemId) T
WHERE T.propCount = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT prop) FROM #P)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is correct that you only get one row for T2, you should get 3 for T1

Comment: select items.* from items inner join items_to_props
    where t = T1 and t= T2 

i know that's is wrong but i dont know how to get 1 row with teh item that have the 2 prpos